# What does "Power consumption max. 100 mA" mean?

Tags: power

I have found a lot of electronic devices with this technical specification:

"Power consumption max. 100 mA" (You can search on the net with this string and you will see a lot of matches.)

What does it mean? Why do they express the power in mA?

Here is an example of datasheet having the power consumption max. in mA:

[image]
Source: https://www.welotec-automation.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/OWLEF-Datasheet-EN.pdf

Comment: It make sense if voltage is given.

Comment: It may also mean that regardless of voltage, power is limited through some point in the circuit due to a current limit, rather than a "power" limit. In other words, given more voltage, power may increase.  Could be that someone needed to provide a max power because of some requirement, and that was the most appropriate thing they could come up with.

Comment: My first impression is that the device has a linear regulator (or something similar) and it needs a current of max 100 mA. In that case power consumption is dependent on input voltage and it is more informative to list max current.

Answer (score 12):

> What does it mean?

In this particular case, it means that it's a linguistic carbon copy from German.

In German, *Stromverbrauch* means current consumption/use, as opposed to let's say *Energieverbrauch* meaning energy use. Yet the noun *Strom* (current) is also used in words that deal with power, such as *Stromversorgung* - literally current supply, but always used to mean *power supply*.

The idiomatic uses reinforce the "confusion" between current and power. *Gibt es Strom?* literally means "Is there current", but idiomatically it means "Is there electric power?".

That's perhaps why it's easy to mix those up when translating.

> Why do they express the power in mA?

They mean to express current, but the idiomatic use of the term *Strom* has clouded their linguistic judgment :)

I'm sure they'd appreciate if you'd kindly point it out to the company, so they fix their materials :)

Answer (score 5):

“Power” is used in more than one way in English, for example it is completely correct to say:

Power (requirements): <100mA at 12~28VDC.

It would be better if they said “current draw” but I don’t think there is any uncertainty in the intended meaning so there is not much point in being pedantic. It's not uncommon to find awkward or somewhat incorrect terminology used in technical documents translated from another language, as I can attest from years of reading "epoch making" Japanese documents in translation.

In this case, the original German word appears to have been "Stromaufnahme" which machine-translates into either "current consumption" or "power consumption". We see an ambiguity [here](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/german-english/stromaufnahme):

> Die ursprünglich minimale Stromaufnahme bedeutete technisch aber auch
> eine sehr genaue Fertigung, eine aufwändige manuelle Feineinstellung
> war notwendig.
>
> Der Zeitverlauf der Stromaufnahme der Spule ist dabei unabhängig von
> der tatsächlich erzeugten Spannung.

Translated by Google as:

> The originally minimal power consumption also meant technically very
> precise production; complex manual fine-tuning was necessary.
>
> The time course of the current consumption of the coil is independent
> of the voltage actually generated.

Maybe a fluent German speaker can clarify or expand upon this.

Comment: Dang, you got the linguistic angle already. Anyway, I'll leave my answer up, since I came up with an independent take on the same thing :) It's guesswork at what linguistic construct exactly threw the translator off, but we both see that it's a linguistic carbon copy issue. Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

If the device had voltage in its specifications, it might be more informative for the user to be informed about the current rather than about the power.

Comment: It does. It says it requires a power supply of 12-28VDC. This is fairly standard for industrial equipment, usually they'll be fed with something they call 12V that's not 12V but always higher (usually about 13.8, especially '12V' from simple transformers with a full rectifier) or something that's actually stable 24V from a mostly decent PSU.